# Why is $E[|Y|^q]=E[\liminf_{n \to \infty} |Y_n|^q]$

Tags: probability-theory

Given a sequence $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ . If $Y_n  \to Y$ in probability and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|Y_n|^q]  < \infty$ for some $1 \leq p <q$ then
$$E[|Y|^q]=E[\liminf_{n \to  \infty} |Y_n|^q]$$

Why is this implication true? I tried using the definition of convergence in probability but couldnt figure out why this is true?

Comment: Look at Fatou's Lemma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma at the paragraph Convergence in measure.

Comment: Do you use $p$ somewhere... Is it a typo?

Comment: @Stef. Actually I didnt write the complete statement which says that given what i have stated above we have that $Y_n \to Y  $ in $ L^P$

Comment: Ok, thanks for the notice.

Comment: @BeniBogosel I read the paragraph on Convergence in measure but i don't see why there is an equality . I would be grateful if you could help me out

Answer (score 6):

The claim is not correct as the following counterexample shows:

Consider $((0,1],\mathcal{B}(0,1])$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure. Define a sequence of random variables by

$$\begin{align*} Y_1(\omega) &:= 1-1_{(1/2,1]}(\omega) \\ Y_2(\omega) &:= 1 - 1_{(0,1/2]}(\omega) \\ Y_3(\omega) &:= 1-1_{(3/4,1]}(\omega) \\ Y_4(\omega) &:= 1-1_{(1/2,3/4]}(\omega) \\ \vdots & \end{align*}$$

Then it is not difficult to see that $Y_n \to Y=1$ in probability, but

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} Y_n = 0.$$ Hence,

$$1 = \mathbb{E}(|Y|^q) \neq \mathbb{E} \left( \liminf_{n \to \infty} |Y_n|^q \right)=0.$$

Comment: :) insightful +1

Comment: @saz But saz I am trying to show that if assumption I mentioned above are true i.e Given a sequence $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ . If $Y_n  \to Y$ in probability and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|Y_n|^q]  < \infty$ for some $1 \leq p <q$ then $Y_n \to Y$ in $L^p$. To show this I use this I need to apply Minkowski's inequality first(on $||Y_n||_{q}$ and $||Y||_{q}$ and  show that $||Y_n-Y||_{q} < \infty \forall n $. But then to apply the Minkowski's inequality I need $E[|Y|^q] < \infty$. And I am proving this by Fatou's lemma

Comment: @saz and now Fatou's lemma only says that $E[\liminf_{n \to \infty}|Y_n|^q] \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} E[|Y_n|^q] \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E[|Y_n|^q] < \infty $. But I somehow need to bring $E[|Y|^q]$ into the picture to make the proof work. And then once I have this I apply the Holder's inequality to complete the proof

Comment: @saz your counterexample ofcourse clearly disproves my statement but then I how to I make the proof work ?

Comment: @user3503589 Please ask a new question. Answering (new) questions in comments is tedious and, moreover, not welcomed here.

Comment: @saz I asked the question again here :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219647/why-is-the-first-equality-of-this-proof-valid?noredirect=1#comment2481960_1219647 .