# Why is the first equality of this proof valid?

Tags: probability-theory

> *Proposition*: Given a sequence $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real-valued random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}.\mathbb{P})$, if $Y_n \to Y $ in probability and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|Y_n|^q] < \infty$ for some $1 \leq p <q$ then $Y_n \to Y $ also in $L^p$.

*Proof.* By Fatou's lemma we have
\begin{align*}
E[|Y|^q] &= E[\liminf_{n \to \infty}|Y_n|^q] \label{star}\tag{*}\\
&\leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}E[|Y_n|^q] \\
&=\sup_{n \geq 0}(\inf_{k \geq n} E[|Y_n|^q]) \\
&\leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|Y_n|^q] < \infty.
\end{align*}

It then follows that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|Y_n|-Y]^q < \infty$ by Minkowski's inequality . Furthermore we can use holder's inequality for $ \frac{p}{q}$ and $\frac{q}{q-p}$ for every $\epsilon >0$ and use the above assumptions to conclude that $Y_n \to Y$ in $L^p$. (I didn't write the rest of the proof to save time)

What I do not follow is why is the first equality \eqref{star} true? This question is related to the question I asked
[Why is $E[|Y|^q]=E[\liminf_{n \to \infty} |Y_n|^q]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214683/why-is-eyq-e-liminf-n-to-infty-y-nq) a few days back but @saz proved that the first inequality does not work by giving a  counterexample. But then in that case  this proof fails. But its in my class notes and most probably it shouldn't have any errors. It is really troubling me. Could someone please show me a way around so that i could make this proof work or proof it in some other way?

Comment: Since you have convergence in probability, a subsequence will converge almost surely. That $\liminf$ should be along this subsequence.

Comment: @TyrCurtis. I am still confused. So there exits a subsequence along which $Y_n \to Y$ a.s. that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n=Y  a.s \implies \lim_{n \to \infty }|Y_n|^q=|Y|^q $ a.s $\implies \liminf_{n \to \infty} |Y_n|^q=|Y|^q  $ a.s because the liminf and lim should agree if the limit exists and then we take the expectations.

Comment: @TyrCurtis Moreover I do not understand why would the liminf be along this subsequence. Liminf is the infimum of all subsequential limits of a sequence , so how do we know for sure that $Y $ is the infimum of all of the subsequences of the sequence $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean I'm afraid. If the limit of something exists, then yes it is equal to the liminf. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @TyrCurtis I know that if the lim exists then it must be equal to liminf. I do not follow why the second equality here is valid $|Y|^q= \lim_{j \to \infty } |Y_{n_j}|^q= \liminf_{n \to \infty }|Y_n|^q $(all equalities here are a.s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214683/why-is-eyq-e-liminf-n-to-infty-y-nq), the equality $(\star)$ does not hold true. However, the inequality

$$\mathbb{E}(|Y|^q) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|Y_n|^q) $$

is correct (- and that's what is actually needed in the proof). *Indeed:* It follows from the very definition of $\liminf$, that there exists a subsequence $(Y_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|Y_n|^q) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|Y_{n_k}|^q). \tag{1}$$

Since $Y_n \to Y$ in probability, we can choose a subsequence $Y_{n_{k_{\ell}}}$ such that $Y_{n_{k_{\ell}}} \to Y$ almost surely.  Now Fatou's lemma shows

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(|Y|^q) &\leq \liminf_{\ell \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|Y_{n_{k_{\ell}}}|^q) \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \liminf_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|Y_n|^q). \end{align*}$$

Comment: If $X_n \to X  $ in probability then $X_n \to \ X$ in distribution . In that case can't we say that $E[|X|^q]=E[\liminf_{n \to \infty} |X_n|^q]$ as $F(x_n) \to F(x) \forall points of continuity \implies  $ their expectations should be the same as well(after raising it to the power q). This is ofcourse incorrect given your counterexample but where am I wrong ? this is probably a very stupid question . Thanks for your patience

Comment: @user3503589 Why should $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ imply $$\mathbb{E}(|X|^q) =  \mathbb{E} \left( \liminf_{n \to \infty} |X_n|^q \right)$$ ....?

Comment: I think I am wrong . :(